# PHP hmac_hash of 1B constant whit fixed value 1

Tags: php, cryptography

im trying to solve some code for authorization to remote service, in "manual" they ask me to generate some keys by hash hmac_sha256, auth codes and etc. First key i should generate is:

key1 = Hmac_Sha256(shared_key, 0x01) where  0x01 is 1B constant (whit fixed value 1) key1 will be used as encryption key (32B)

**question is how to write 1B constant 0x01 in PHP?**

I got this from developers to test code:

shared_key (base64)

```
bRtFEufmEgrJyhai6ltDSV9svtpN3Jb/5oWBBYhDJ30=
```

in hex:

```
6D 1B 45 12 E7 E6 12 0A C9 CA 16 A2 EA 5B 43 49
5F 6C BE DA 4D DC 96 FF E6 85 81 05 88 43 27 7D
```

and generated key1 should by:

```
DE B5 81 AB EC C4 A5 A5 5D C7 6C 08 A9 75 49 62
BD A0 54 10 E1 A3 0D 5E 99 05 AD FA 65 6C F2 C9
```

mine current code is

```
<?php
define('bit_1', 0x01);
$shared_key = 'bRtFEufmEgrJyhai6ltDSV9svtpN3Jb/5oWBBYhDJ30=';
$shared_key = base64_decode($shared_key); //HEX is correct

$key1 = hash_hmac('sha256', bit_1, $shared_key, true); //HEX is wrong
//7C 07 BE BD FA 97 70 7A 0C 41 CF 9A 4D 1E B0 68
//9D A8 52 FE D4 D8 E7 CC C5 0C 61 F8 7A B0 B5 19
```

i also tryed bit_1 as (int)1, (string)'1' all produce same wrong key1, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x01` is hexadecimal notation to create an `int`, which is more than 1 byte. What you want is to express raw bytes directly, for which you use a string in PHP (strings are mere byte arrays):

```
"\x01"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write byte literals with the `\xXY` notation. In you case: `"\x01"`.

There are also some other ways. For example: `pack("H*", "01")` and `pack("C*", 1)`